# error while trying to run make command

Tags: linux, git, makefile, terminal, vivado

I'm trying to clone and make this project to use in Vivado:
https://github.com/olajep/parallella-fpga/tree/2016.11
after I've cloned it then I use git submodule init and the gir submodule update command.
after that I used make command and I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 , Vivado 2015.2 and gcc 7.3.0
what should I do?
thanks

Comment: »» /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found «« : Looks like you have an old `libstdc++` in /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

You need to download and install the missing dependencies in order for your `make` command to work.